# Debouncing input in Vue with variable wait time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, debouncing

I would like to debounce input fields in Vue, which is pretty straightforward, except I want to make the debounce wait time configurable per field, which is apparently not so straightforward.

My input fields are backed by objects, like so:

```
filters: [
    {
    title: 'Foo',
    value: null,
    debounce: 1200
  },
    {
    title: 'Bar',
    value: null,
    debounce: 400
  }
]
```

Then I create the input fields using these objects:

```
  <div v-for="filter in filters">
    <input type="text" @input="debounceInput($event, filter)" :value="filter.value">
    <span>{{ filter.value }}</span>
  </div>
```

I'm using the Lodash `debounce` method like this, which works fine:

```
  methods: {
    debounceInput: _.debounce((event, filter) => {
        filter.value = event.target.value;
    }, 500)
  }
```

But I would really like to make the debounce wait time configurable. It is stored in `filter`, but since filter is passed to `_.debounce` as a parameter, I cannot access it outside of `_.debounce`, which is what I actually need to do.

I've tried wrapping an anonymous function around the call to debounce (which seemed like the most obvious solution to me), like so:

```
debounceInputVariable(event, filter) {
    return _.debounce((event, filter) => {
      filter.value = event.target.value;
    }, filter.debounce)
}
```

But that doesn't work. I've also experimented with `bind` and `call` to no avail.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/ma6nvqzh/

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method to generate the debounce functions for each filter:

```js
generateDebouncers() {
  this.filters.forEach(filter => {
    Vue.set(filter, 'debouncer', _.debounce(function(event) {
      filter.value = event.target.value;
    }, filter.debounce));
  });
}
```

This creates a `debouncer` property on each filter, a function to be called in the template like this:

```html
<input type="text" @input="filter.debouncer" :value="filter.value">
```

You can initialize this in `created` or call it in a deep watch on `filters` if you need it to react to filter duration changes.

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/ws9raxdc/)

Comment: Sadly, no... That just creates a new instance of the debounced function (and executes it) on every input event, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! In my actual app I have a factory function for the filters and I added it there. Now each filter has a `debounce` property that contains the debounce function.